# How do I send data using low bluetooth energy in flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I have a Project to send data from flutter to Arduino to do some tasks, I was working with HC -05 and 'serial Bluetooth communication library' but I found that isn't support Low energy Bluetooth, so I have to work with 'flutter_blue' and I can't find exactly how just send data like "1"
if someone has already work with something like that, help me and thanks

method to how can I send data with this library "Flutter blue"

Comment: You can refer this link, it provides example code: [ClickHere](https://blog.kuzzle.io/communicate-through-ble-using-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

'how can I send data with this library "Flutter blue"?'

There is an example there in flutter blue page (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) on how to get and send data to a BLE device.

await c.write([0x12, 0x34])

There are initial steps before the app can read and write data to the BLE device. Basically, the steps consists of scanning, connecting, and discovering services. After that, the app can start reading and writing data. Data are written(or read) to (or from) a 'characteristics'. The app can also subscribe to a characteristics so it can receive data from the notification. These are just a general guide for communicating with BLE devices. You must know the details from the documentation of the specific device.